# while loop - variable x is not incremented

Tags: r

## Sequential similarity of similar scale

```
    library(quantmod)

    #input symbol, start and end dates:

    my_symbol<-readline("What symbol would you like analyzed?")
    start_date <- readline("When do you want the series to start?")
    end_date <- readline("When do you want the series to end?")

    start_date2 <- readline("When do you want the scaled series to start?")
    end_date2 <- readline("When do you want the scaled series to end?")

    data1 <- as.data.frame(getSymbols(my_symbol, from = start_date, to = end_date, env = NULL)) 
    data2<- getSymbols(my_symbol, from = start_date2, to = end_date2, env = NULL)
    data3<- as.ts(data2[,4])

    section<-length(data3)/3
    #divide subset into 3 sections

    subdata1<-data3[1:section]
    subdata2<-data3[section:(section*2)]
    subdata3<-data3[(section*2):(section*3)]


    section2<-length(subdata1)
    testdata1<-data1[,4]
    testdata2<-testdata1[1:section2]

    #Iterate through testdata

    len2<-length(subdata1)
    while (x < 0.67){
      x<-0.66
      resize<-approx(seq_along(subdata1), subdata1, n = len2*x)$y
      len<-length(resize)
      for (i in testdata1){
        testdata2<-testdata1[(1+i):(len+i)]
        corl<-cor(testdata2, resize)
        if (corl>0.6){
          maxes<-c(corl, len, i)
          #print(maxes)
            }
        print(len)
          }

      x<-(x+0.01)
        }
```

my X variable in the while loop remains static and does not change. which is strange considering that the while loop breaks after sometime. The length remains the same as evident by the line print(len),

what can be done?

Comment: Based on that code I'd say you'll only get one run of the while loop.

Comment: I'm new to coding, can you please guide me through how to do it?

Comment: How does the `while` loop even run? The `x` is undefined when the loop begins.

Comment: At the start of the loop you're setting x to 0.66, at the end you're incrementing it by 0.01 which makes it 0.67 which makes it exit the loop.

Comment: OH! I'm sorry I have been running a 48 hour session learning to code! Thanks for all your help! It works now!

Comment: Perhaps you want to put the x<-0.66 outside the loop and then increment by something smaller, say 0.001.

Comment: I did that, thanks for your help Steve!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wording my comments as an answer since they helped resolve/dissolve the problem.

As given the `while` loop will only execute once. At the start you have `x<-0.66` and at the end `x<-(x+0.01)` which makes `x=0.67` which then causes you to exit the loop since the condition for the loop is `while (x<0.67)`.

You should move the initial setting of x outside the loop since otherwise it will be reset each time and if the loop doesn't exit on the first run it will loop infinitely. Then to run the loop more than once you could replace `x<-(x+0.01)` with, say, `x<-(x+0.001)`.